# Create a customized connector line using VISIO 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm working with Visio 2013 Professional on Microsoft Windows 7, it is my first time using Visio and I need to create a customized connector with automatic arrows in the corners of the line, to indicate the flow, something like the picture attached and I also need to change the flow direction sometimes.

Do you know if it is possible to do it using the developer area, or another trick?

I've checked the default arrow styles and it creates an automatic arrow just in the end of the connection. For now every time I bend a connection I need to insert a triangle manually to indicate the flow.

[image: connector line with arrows]

Answer (score 0):

**IMHO** It is impossible because connectors behavior are managed by Visio engine ! Connectors can re-routed and so on